# AsyncTask error within SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, supportmapfragment

DoInBackground work fine, locals var is loaded without problem, but when doinBackground return Local[] get RunTimeException and I don´t know about that.

Here below I show my`SupportMapFragment` class implementation and Exception.

```
public class LocalMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

    private Local[] locals;
    private MapDrawer mapDrawer;

    public LocalMapFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_local, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state) {
        super.onActivityCreated(state);

        new MapLocals(this).execute();
    }

    public void initMap(Local[] locals) {

        this.mapDrawer = new MapDrawer(this.getMap());

        this.locals = locals;

        this.mapDrawer.showLocals(this.locals);
    }

    static class MapLocals extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Local[]> {

        LocalMapFragment localMapFragment;

        public MapLocals(LocalMapFragment localMapFragment) {

            this.localMapFragment = localMapFragment;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        protected Local[] doInBackground(String... params) {

            Local[] locals = null;

            try {

                LocalService localService = new LocalService(this.localMapFragment.getActivity(),
                        "/rest/localList.json");

                locals = localService.getLocalsFromUserCity();
            } catch (Exception ex) {

                Log.e("APPERROR", ex.getMessage());
            }

            return locals;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Local[] locals) {

            this.localMapFragment.initMap(locals);

            /*
             * int x = 0; x = x + 2;
             * 
             * FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity) this.context; if
             * (activity != null && !activity.isFinishing()) {
             * 
             * initMap(locals); }
             */
        }
    }
}
```

**LogCat:**

```
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.myapp/com.myapp.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2216)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at maps.ag.bg.b(Unknown Source)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at bob.onTransact(SourceFile:115)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onResume(Unknown Source)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onResume(Unknown Source)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh$6.b(Unknown Source)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.a(Unknown Source)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.onResume(Unknown Source)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onResume(Unknown Source)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1521)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:963)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:1887)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:460)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:449)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5107)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2718)
10-04 11:00:04.566: E/AndroidRuntime(9542):     ... 12 more
```

Comment: From your logcat it indicates that there is nullpointer exception in your `HomeActivity` resume method.

Comment: Is false, I have debugged and work fine HomeActivity onResume method. I think real problem is from "Caused By" until the end.

Comment: mmmm, I see now problem is not AsyncTask... I am finding about problem...

Comment: Yes you are on track its other problem. Try to debug and check for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your GoogleMap object is not created when your are trying to paint the local markets on it. TYou may use this method (from the Google maps for Android documentation) inside the fragement "onStart()":

```
    /**
     * Method to set up map. It must be called at onCreate() and onResume() to assure map has been initialized
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (googleMap == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.main_map);
            GoogleMap gmap = mapFragment.getMap();

            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (gmap != null) {
                googleMap = new GoogleMapsManager(mapFragment, getBaseContext(), this);
            }
        }
    }
```

When you got your response back from the AsyncTask, check again if you got already this googleMap object and then put the markers on it.